# Print out the data in batches as insertion order

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, data-structures

I have this code to printout all the registered passenger's details:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < a; counter++) {
    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println("Name: " + PassengerName[counter]);
    System.out.println("ID Number: " + PassengerIDNum[counter]);
    System.out.println("Mobile Number: " + PassengerMobNum[counter]);
    System.out.println("Temperature in °C: " + PassengerTemp[counter]);
}
```

This is the output:

```
==============================
Name: PassengerA
ID Number: 12345
Mobile Number: 23456
Temperature in °C: 36.5
==============================
Name: PassengerB
ID Number: 34567
Mobile Number: 45678
Temperature in °C: 35.4
==============================
Name: PassengerForTesla
ID Number: 5678
Mobile Number: 6789
Temperature in °C: 35.6
==============================
```

These inputs are grouped into batches.
`PassengerA` and `PassengerB` belong to the first batch of input and `PassengerForTesla` belongs to the second batch input.

As I use Array I can not print those by batches. What's the way to preserve batch information.

Comment: Don't use a for loop if you want to print one entry.

Comment: *FYI:* You may want to create a class `Passenger` with the attributes `name`, `idNum`, `mobNum` and so on. Then you won't need to mess around with arrays like that.

Comment: what do you mean by "first" and "second" input?

Comment: But i don't know how many passenger's information will be entered by the user at the beginning of my code.

Comment: I already have a class for Passenger, so i need to use the getter and setter methods?

Comment: This is a system for user to input the information. For example a family with four person, so this four person will be considered as the first input. When the next people come in, the information entered by the next people (not the family members), it will considered as the second input.

Comment: you need a way to distinguish those groups of people, like an attribute `groupId`. Otherwise, there is no criteria to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best if you create a passenger class like this:

```
class Passenger {
    private string name;
    private int idNumber;
    private string mobileNumber;
    private int temperature;
    private int inputNumber;
   
    public Passenger(string name, int idNumber, string mobileNumer, int temperature, int inputNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        ....
    }
    public int getInputNumber() { return inputNumber;}

    public void print(){
         System.println(name);
         System.println(idNumber);
         ....
    }
}
```

This should solve your problems. You can now have a List of Passengers and print out only the ones with a certain inputNumber. Also for convenience sake I'd put a print() method in the passenger class.

So your for() loop would look something like this:

```
for (Passenger p: myPassengerList) {
     if(p.getInputNumber() == THE_NUMBER_I_WANT_TO_BE_PRINTED) p.print();
}
```

The reason for using a list and passenger objects instead of multiple arrays is because storing data which belongs together in the same class is a lot easier to work with and in general it's just a better style of programming.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: For the for-loop, the Passenger p: myPassengerList is the array list?

Comment: Yes, the `for(Passenger p: myPassengerList)` is going through every Passenger in that list (it's called a "foreach" loop). So you have a `List<Passenger> myPassengerList` and with the foreach you go through every Passenger contained in that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct main method logic accordingly, this could be the basic block

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  static List<List<Passenger>> allPassengers = new ArrayList<List<Passenger>>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Passenger PassengerA = new Passenger("PassengerA", 12345, "23456", 36.5F);
    Passenger PassengerB = new Passenger("PassengerB", 34567, "45678", 35.4F);
    Passenger PassengerForTesla = new Passenger("PassengerForTesla", 5678, "6789", 35.6F);

    List<Passenger> firstSet = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
    firstSet.add(PassengerA);
    firstSet.add(PassengerB);
    allPassengers.add(firstSet);

    List<Passenger> secondSet = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
    secondSet.add(PassengerForTesla);
    allPassengers.add(secondSet);

    for (int i = 0; i < allPassengers.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("****print " + (i + 1) + " set passengers****");
      print(allPassengers.get(i));

    }

  }

  private static void print(List<Passenger> passengers) {
    for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {
      System.out.println(passenger + "\n");
    }

  }

}
```

and the Passenger class is

```
public class Passenger {
  /*
   * Name: PassengerA ID Number: 12345 Mobile Number: 23456 Temperature in °C: 36.5
   */
  String name;
  int id;
  String mobile;
  float temp;

  public Passenger(String name, int id, String mobile, float temp) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.temp = temp;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "==============================" + "\nName: " + name + "\nID Number: " + id
        + "\nMobile Number: " + mobile + "\nTemperature in °C: " + temp;
  }

}
```

out will be

```
****print 1 set passengers****
==============================
Name: PassengerA
ID Number: 12345
Mobile Number: 23456
Temperature in °C: 36.5

==============================
Name: PassengerB
ID Number: 34567
Mobile Number: 45678
Temperature in °C: 35.4

****print 2 set passengers****
==============================
Name: PassengerForTesla
ID Number: 5678
Mobile Number: 6789
Temperature in °C: 35.6
```

Comment: based on how you want to print, whether to print last, and all input you may change the logic on main method accordingly

Comment: but the passenger information need to based on the user input

Comment: yes, you must have already know how to get the user input I guess. you need to convert those to passenger object that is explained here(see passenger object creation)

Comment: what is your question? is it about how you going to store input for easy processing, this is the answer. You have to have a Passenger class and an arraylist to store them.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike posting 2 answers but I can't comment under @Java Newbie's answer (pls someone just give me an upvote or smth, I can only comment with 50+ reputation) so here you go:

Yes, storing an Array inside an Array is possible. It's called a 2D Array and looks like this: `String[][] myArray = new String[someValue][someValue]`
Although this is possible, I would very much advise against it. It is a lot better to use Lists. The following code might seem a little complex compared to using a 2D-Array but it is in my opinion the best and only proper way to write this code

```
List<Ride> rides = new ArrayList<Ride>();

public class Ride {
    private List<Passenger> passengers;
    private VehicleInformation vehicleInformation;
    //You need to add a constructor and getters and setters
}
```

This way you have a Ride which contains a List of passengers and one car (rule of thumb: if your data structure sounds like a sentence someone would say then it's probably good).

Now if you want to know who rode with vehicle XYZ then you can go through the `rides` List, select all rides with one vehicle and print the passenger informations. This is something you most likely will want to do in the future and it will be a lot harder to do with arrays.
With lists you can go

```
List<Passenger> passengersOfCarXYZ = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
for(Ride r: rides){
   if(r.getVehicle().getName().equals("XYZ")) passengersOfCarXYZ.add(r.getPassengers());
}
```

and have all the passengers of a car. It doesn't get much simpler than this.

Using arrays for this is possible but it's the definition of bad coding haha